# Having trouble starting up my react native project on expo and/or android emulator

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, expo

```
[object Object]
WARNING in ./node_modules/expo-router/src/exports.ts:26
export 'ErrorBoundaryProps' (reexported as 'ErrorBoundaryProps') was not found in './views/Try' (possible exports: Try)
  24 | export { ExpoRoot } from "./ExpoRoot";
  25 | export { Unmatched } from "./views/Unmatched";
> 26 | export { ErrorBoundaryProps } from "./views/Try";
  27 | export { ErrorBoundary } from "./views/ErrorBoundary";
  28 |
  29 | // Platform

ERROR in ./node_modules/expo-router/_ctx.web.tsx:1:19
Module not found: Can't resolve '..\..\app'
> 1 | export const ctx = require.context(
    |                   ^
  2 |   process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT!,
  3 |   true,
  4 |   /.*/,

web compiled with 1 error and 1 warning
```

Getting this error whenever I run expo start.

Checked both ./views/Try and ErrorBoundaryProps looks like it is getting properly exported. Not sure what's going on with the EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT...

Not sure where to even start.